# I want to add a copy of the first column as a new column at the end of the array, can someone explain the difference in dimentions of the error?

Tags: python, numpy

```
b = np.concatenate((a, a[:,0]), axis=1)
```

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want to hear but `a[:,0]` is a 1-d array, not a 2-d array. Its shape is (n,), not (1,n).

Comment: `a[:,0].reshape(2, 1)` will make it work...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an extra column to a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8486294/6045800) or [How to duplicate a row or column in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43870647/6045800)

Comment: I got it, it was the shape yes

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
np.c_[a,a[:,0]]
```

otherwise you should reshape `a[:,0]` as:

```
np.concatenate((a,a[:,0].reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)
```

this because `a[:,0]` is a 1d array and you will not have a second axis (`axis=1`). This explains the error "the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)"